# How can I try to create a date object and set invalid parameters to 1?

Tags: python, date, validation

I'm creating a program in python where the user is required to enter a date (day month and year), and any parts of the date that are invalid should be set to 1. For example, if they enter the date 31/31/2019 it would be changed to 1/1/2019. I'm not totally sure how to go about doing this. I decided it would be best to create a method that would do it, here's what it is so far:

```
def create_date(day, month, year):
    safe_day = 1
    safe_month = 1
    safe_year = 1

    if day > 31 or day < 1:
        day = safe_day
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        month = safe_month
    if year > 9999 or year < 1:
        year = safe_year

    try:
        final_date = date(day, month, year)
        return final_date
    except ValueError:
        #no idea what to put here
        pass
```

Right now I have just a try-except, the except block just holds a pass statement as a placeholder. I figure I could fix it if I could find out which parameter(s) are causing it, but the only way I could think of would be to brute force it and test 7 different cases, which is very...undesirable.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: IMO, you should raise the error and not try to second guess the user's intent.

Comment: @Alexander Well it's for school and the instructions require it.

Comment: Why would it raise an exception in the first place? You're validating the input before using it anyways

Comment: `dt.date(31, 2, 2019)` would cause a ValueError.

Comment: Instead of `pass`, try `return date(1, month, year)`.

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky Not exactly, although you do give me an idea. I make sure that year and month are right, but not each month has the same amount of days. Like this, it will keep the value of day the same if it's 31, but not all months have that many dates. I guess I should just use those if statements and then if it throws an exception then set day to 1.

Answer (score 0):

What I realized I need to do, thanks to a comment from [Marsilinou Zaky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8692977/marsilinou-zaky) is to have the except return date(1, month, year). The month and year are already being validated, the day is being validated as well, to a certain extent. The if statement makes sure it's between 1 and 31 (both inclusive) but that won't work for all months since the amount of days varies. Since at this point only days could screw it up I'd only ever need to set that to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try catching it this way, also keep in mind that date takes arguments in order

```
date(year, month, day) --> date object  
#You can use print(help(date)) for refrence
```

.

```
from datetime import *
def create_date(year, month, day):
    safe_day = 1
    safe_month = 1
    safe_year = 1
    if day > 31 or day < 1:
        day = safe_day
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        month = safe_month
    if year > 31 or year < 1:
        year = safe_year

    try:
        final_date = date(year, month, day)
        return final_date
    except ValueError:
        if month == 2:
            if year % 4 != 0:
                day = 28
            else:
                day = 29
        else:
            day = 30
        return date(year, month, day)
```